# What is the meaning of rectangle areas with stripes, while having test coverage enabled in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, code-coverage

Xcode 9.2. I have enabled test coverage, written some tests and run them.

On the right side of the editor, Xcode shows if a code has been tested or not by displaying red or green rectangles.

However, I don't know what is the meaning of a rectangle with stripes.

I have not managed to find an answer in Xcode guides or help files.

Screenshot:

[image: code coverage - red rectangle with stripes]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The striped rectangles indicate partial code coverage. Somebody just asked this question elsewhere and in looking at some test cases, I realized that if you hover your mouse over a line with the stripes, you get something like this:

[image: Partial code coverage]

As you'll notice, part of the line is green and part of it is red. The green part is for the condition which comes under code coverage since that part was executed. The red part is for the error message which was not executed since the test passed. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Fahim, thanks for noticing that. This was me asking on the forum. I wonder why did Apple do that like this in test files.

Comment: I believe they wanted to more accurately reflect the code coverage since in the case of tests, you would want both branches of the code to be tested. I am curious as to what happens if you write a Red test and then make it go green though. Does Xcode somehow record that both branches were covered? I should test to see what happens, but haven't tried that yet ...